Display sleep issue on the monitor after approximately 10 minutes of inactivity
We are experiencing a display sleep issue on the monitor after approximately 10 minutes of inactivity. Despite modifying the lightdm configuration file, the issue persists. Could you please suggest an effective solution to resolve this?

You've not told us what Ubuntu product & release you're using, lightdm isn't the default DM for Ubuntu anyway (hasn't been since Ubuntu 17.04 or the 2017-April release), so what are you running?
